# the events that get triggered after pressing lock button from windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8

Creating an application where I need to implement the functionality of lock button of windows phone.

Anyone knows which method or event gets triggered when Lock button is pressed.
I tried searching in various namespaces, but didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look for the `OnSuspending` Event in `App.xaml.cs` and its counterpart the `resuming` event.

See Dokumentation:
Suspending: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.application.suspending.aspx
Resuming: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.application.resuming.aspx

Answer (score 0):

May be [obscured](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.obscured(v=vs.105).aspx) and [unobscured](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.unobscured(v=vs.105).aspx) events are what you need. [This page](http://www.dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=210)  explains the solution very well. You can register these events in any page you want to do that. For example add below lines of code in the constructor of the MainPage.xaml.cs. Create instance of RootFrame and add Obscured and Unobscured event to it.

```
PhoneApplicationFrame rootFrame = (Application.Current as App).RootFrame;
rootFrame.Obscured += OnObscured;
rootFrame.Unobscured += Unobscured;
```

Add OnObscured method and Unobscured method. OnObscured method will be triggered when phone is getting locked and Unobscured event will be triggered when phone is getting unlocked.

```
private void OnObscured(Object sender, ObscuredEventArgs e)
{
    //Code to execute when the phone is getting locked
}

private void Unobscured(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Code to execute when the phone is getting unlocked
}
```

Comment: I come to know that windows phone is not exposing their API for lock button functionality. Am I correct ?
The apps which has already developed are using some third party DLL which is not official.